# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS crashes on wakeup

Tags: 14.04, drivers, video

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.

When I close the lid of my laptop (i.e put on stand by mode) and when I try to resume it the screen doesn't startup. So the only thing I could do is forcefully shut it down.

And every time I boot it comes up with 'System error' window.

How do I fix this?

My video driver:

```
*-display:0
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:44 memory:f8000000-f80fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
     description: Display controller
     product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2.1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:f8100000-f81fffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a similar problem I had when I updated my kernel.

Try [this fix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

As a result, my problem was solved and the "Sleep Mode" works without problems.

Comment: I cant install ATI binary X.Org driver it says I've got issues :
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

fglrx: Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
       Depends: xorg-video-abi-15 but it is a virtual package

Comment: Seems to be a problem affecting 14.04.2.
See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266268&page=4 for a workaround.